# How can I validate Google Login response using keycloak?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, google-api, keycloak

I have a angular web application, I have created login/register functionality using spring boot and keycloak.When user logins or register request sends to backend(spring boot)from angular(front end),then i am storing in keycloak. Now I am integrating google login in angular.
Code blockin angular

```
google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id:'',
      ux_mode: "popup",
      callback: (res: any) => {
        console.log(res)
        this.handleSocialLogin(res);
      }
    });
```

Response

{
"clientId": "123",
"client_id": "123",
"credential": "token",
"select_by": "btn"
}
If I want authorize this google token in keycloak. I have integrated Identity provider in keycloak.How can I validate

My Intention is

Angular -> Google(Response) -> Angular(sending google resposne) -> Spring Boot -> Keycloak(create user based on google token) -> Angular(keycloak resposne)

I have tried
http://localhost:8080/realms/realm/protocol/openid-connect/token - its not working